# WCF UserNameOverTransport best practices to store user name and password

Tags: wcf

In my client application I have to use web service UserNameOverTransport, so I need in client set username and password like:

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "account";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

Is it some best practices where store username and password?

From my point of view it isn't good idea to store credentials in config file.

[Update]
When I asked this question I though that WCF provide some standard ability to store credentials in config file or have ability to setup with help of endpoints behaiviours.

The example which I looked for is solution by the following link:
http://blog.shutupandcode.net/?p=22

Comment: Are the username and password fixed for all clients? If that is the case then you can have them in the config but make sure to encrypt them and the decryption part should be on your server.

Comment: Nope, it can't be fixed for all clients.

Comment: Then that needs to be an input from each client like a web page asking for credentials or if its a windows app then a form asking for credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store credentials in the app.config/web.config, you can encrypt them using the `ProtectedData` class or a `ProtectedConfigurationProvider`. See the following links for more info (ordered from least detailed to most):

http://geekswithblogs.net/afeng/archive/2006/12/10/100821.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to store your username and password in config. What you usually store in config are client settings, like endpoints, behaviours and security settings.

Username and password should be set from inside the code, like you have shown:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "account";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

It's completely up to you where you will get these values from and how you are going to secure it

Comment: It would be nice to save ability to change credentials without re-build.

Comment: @Vadim911 Do not hardcode anything, just read it from place that is convinient for you. You can have it encrypted somewhere, or just ask user to type it in. That's just the way to set it from the code.